# Cannot copy from child directory to parent directory

Tags: r, shell

When passing commands to shell() in RStudio using R 3.6.3, files can be copied from a parent directory to a child directory, but not from a child directory to the parent. The code below fails on line 4

```
dir1 <- "C:/Users/henry/Desktop"
dir2 <- "C:/Users/henry/Desktop/New"
shell(paste0("copy ", "\"", dir1, "/text.txt", "\" \"", dir2, "/text2.txt", "\""))
shell(paste0("copy ", "\"", dir2, "/text2.txt", "\" \"", dir1, "/text3.txt", "\""))
```

with this error

```
Warning message:
In shell(paste0("copy ", "\"", dir2, "/text2.txt", "\" \"", dir1,  :
  'copy "C:/Users/henry/Desktop/New/text2.txt" "C:/Users/henry/Desktop/text3.txt"' execution failed with error code 1
```

I've tried this with several different directories in different locations and the problem is always the same. It works if I run the commands directly in cmd. Ultimately, I'm not actually trying to copy files, I'm trying to send a different command that requires the address of an exe file and the address of another file. Couldn't get it working and this is the most minimal example I can provide of the essential problem. This seems bizarre.